# Get dimensions from jQuery ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im trying to get the width of the $('.tools') in this ajax response but it returns 0.

The rest works fine. Only #formWrapper is inserted into content.

```
$.get(path).done(function (data) {
    var fw = $(data).find('#formWrapper');
    $(fw).appendTo($('#content'));
    console.log($('.tools').width());
});
```

html ajax

```
<div id="menu">
menu stuff...
</div>
<div id="formWrapper">
 <select class="tools"><option>test</option></select>
</div>
```

the content div to display the result

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

How can I get the element dimenions ?

Comment: You have to add it to the DOM, otherwise it doesn't have dimensions.

Comment: Please show you html, edit it into the question

Comment: I updated with the html

Comment: Is there any relevant CSS for the markup?

Comment: There is NO css width on the select. And I can't get the dimensions from any other element in that response.

Comment: Are there really no further suggestion? Someone must have experience with this situation.